# how to call 64 bit driver from a 32 bit app

Tags: c++, windows, driver, 32bit-64bit

Using DebugView was easier than I thought. After a few hours, it turns out 64 bit kernel driver IS to blame... Silly me... Duh !

1. How would you fix this
2. Since my individual kernel signing certificate expired and it was a pain to get one the first time and they no longer even sell them.

Can anybody PLEASE re-sign the modified 64 bit sys file just for this one time? I could provide my original previously signed driver, if you need it to binary compare etc.

```
status = ZwDuplicateObject(hProcess,(HANDLE)SysHandle[i].Handle,ZwCurrentProcess(),&ObjectHandle,0, 0, DUPLICATE_SAME_ATTRIBUTES |DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
DbgPrint("status:%d sourceProcess:%p SourceHandle:%d CurrentProcess:%d returnedObjectHandle:%d.\n", RtlNtStatusToDosError(status),hProcess, (HANDLE)SysHandle[i].Handle,PsGetCurrentProcessId(),&ObjectHandle);

//On_32bit  status:0 sourceProcess:80002CB8 SourceHandle:68 CurrentProcess:3984 returnedObjectHandle:-340903132.
//On_64bit  status:0 sourceProcess:FFFFFFFF800001BC SourceHandle:108 CurrentProcess:1996 returnedObjectHandle:221378472.

status = ObReferenceObjectByHandle(ObjectHandle, FILE_ANY_ACCESS, *IoFileObjectType, UserMode, (PVOID*)&FileObject,  &objHandle);
DbgPrint("status %d.\n", RtlNtStatusToDosError(status));

//On_64bit  status=STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE (error 6 here only on 64 bit on 32 it is 0 as expected) !!!???
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: You can't run 32 bit drivers on 64 bit versions of windows.  see the last question here:: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows#1TC=windows-7

Comment: @NathanOliver the question asks how to call 64 bit driver in a 32 bit app.  It appears the OP has a 32 bit app that works on 32 bit windows, but not on 64 bit windows because the driver is 64 bits.

Comment: @891976 this is a vague description of a method that I haven't personally done, but an idea might be to write a 64 bit "helper" or "shim" app that talks to the driver for you.  You then carefully talk to the 64 bit helper app from your 32 bit app.  This makes the 64/32 bit conversation in "user space", instead of in the user/driver space interface.

Comment: How do you create the handle? Coould be the problem lies there and not in this function call.

Comment: its just regular 32bit pointer it is not null. it is valid but maybe somehow it has to be extended to 64 bit handle HANDLE hDev = CreateFile(
  L"\\\\.\\windr",
  GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
  FILE_SHARE_READ,
  NULL,
  OPEN_EXISTING,
  0,
  0
  )

Comment: And you are in fact blindly hoping that this CreateFile() call succeeds?  Sure, then you can only get ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE and not find out why CreateFile failed.

Comment: Is it also not INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE?

Comment: Also it is not a pointer afaik

Comment: So chances are your CreateFile() call fails. Please check for that, figure out why it fails with GetLastError() and report back your findings. Ofcourse, you'd want to also check and triple check that your driver is actually loaded and initialized in the Device Manager.

Comment: Also specify constant strings with TEXT("") not L""

Comment: Nos: No, createfile does not fail hdev returns an 32 bit address like 0x00004724 and err watch only changes after DeviceIoControl is called. 64 bit driver expects a 64 bit address not 32. This could be the cause. Not sure how to implement that though on the 32 bit app side for both 32 and 64 bit drivers, Also, other parameters of that function might need casting or extending. Not sure how to properly code that that's why I asked for help.

Comment: Also the docs say "You should specify the FILE_SHARE_READ andFILE_SHARE_WRITE access flags when callingCreateFile to open a handle to a device driver. "

Comment: fassl: thanks for 2 unrelated tips, but entire app and driver already is use and works as it is on 32 bit without any bugs.

Comment: nos: driver is installed signed and running properly as a 64 bit driver

Comment: You can call a 64-bit driver from 32-bit code safely.  What is the original type of `m_FileName`?  All that casting is suspicious.

Comment: @Mark CAtlString, don't ask me why, because a) not my code b)it works without problems on 32 bit so not going to change the type and mess that up if it is not crucial to fix the invalid 64 bit handle problem.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is because the application is 32 bit?  Does identical code work when compiled as 64 bit?  (It seems more likely that the problem is a bug in the 64-bit driver.)  You shouldn't need to do anything special to call a 64-bit driver from a 32-bit application.

Comment: OK, so the "invalid handle" error is coming from inside the driver, and refers to a handle the driver is using.  Regardless of whether you wind up fixing the driver, or working around the problem from user space, the first thing you need is to understand why it is failing - do you?  It isn't clear to me what that code is trying to do.  The value of hProcess looks suspicious, but that call appears to be succeeding.  Oh, and you probably wanted the value of ObjectHandle in DebugPrint, not the address.

Comment: You can put your system in test signing mode for troubleshooting purposes.  That way you can make changes to the driver as necessary in order to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @Harry, Ok thanks, it is already in that mode and I already printed out 32-64 bit debug values of same code. Only 64 bit has a problem. Question is how do you actually fix it? What other info is necessary to figure this out...? Any solution to that? ANYBODY?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the posted values for objectHandle are correct?  Because they don't look like valid handle values to me.  Since the handle is being duplicated into the handle table of the calling process, you can use user-mode tools like `handle.exe` to examine them.  One possible cause for INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE would be if the handle isn't a file handle.

Comment: ... although it could be just because you're not passing NULL as the final argument to ObReferenceObjectByHandle like the documentation says you should.

Comment: @harry I previously tried NULL too it makes no differrence.  I am sure handles are not proper problem is why not? Biggest clue is same code same app same file path works on 32 does not work on 64. I don't have a 2 or 3 PC setup and dont know how to set it up . So cannot compare a 32 bit vs 64 bit LINE-BY-LINE to figure out if there is a hidden bug above this line. Can anyone with a setup to debug this entire function with calling app included in Visual studio 2008 for me.

Comment: The fact that it works in 32-bit isn't a very useful clue IMO.  I think the first step should be to remove the code (if any) that closes the handle in question, then examine the handle table of the calling application to confirm that the duplicate handle actually exists and is a file handle.  If the handle looks OK, get the application to use it for something - write data to it, read data from it, or whatever is sensible based on where the handle originally came from.  If the handle is there but has a different value to the one you were expecting, that's also a clue.